# The link after e.preventDefault() doesn't load, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events

I want to load a link on click, but it doesn't load. I use `preventDefault()` to load the animation and `setTimeout()`. What else should I use?

I try `return true`, and think to save the path link of the node in a variable and then using `location.href` to call it. But I don't know how to do it.

```
<div class="content animated fadeInDown"> Table </div>

<td>
    <a class="link" href="./pizzerias/lazzaroni.html">See More</a>
</td>

<script>
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

links.forEach((link)=>{
    link.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{

        e.preventDefault();
        let content = document.querySelector('.content');

        content.classList.remove('fadeInDown');
        content.classList.remove('animated');

        content.classList.add('fadeOutUp');
        content.classList.add('animated');

        setTimeout(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` disabled the default behavior of `<a>`, you either need to `removeEventListener` or not using `e.preventDefault()` on a `<a>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) is doing exactly what the name implies. It prevents the default behavior of an event.

In the case of a link, the default behavior is to redirect the user to the associated `href` attribute value.

You are preventing this from happening. So it is never going to happen. The `setTimeout` isn't doing anything either as it is.

If you want to redirect the user after the animation you need to do it explicitely:

```
links.forEach((link)=>{
    link.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{

        e.preventDefault();
        let content = document.querySelector('.content');

        content.classList.remove('fadeInDown');
        content.classList.remove('animated');

        content.classList.add('fadeOutUp');
        content.classList.add('animated');

        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = e.target.href;
        }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` require a callback function as its first argument but you only pass the time. It would be

```
setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = e.target.href
}, 500)
```